# Display image from embedded resource

Tags: image, xaml, svg, maui, embedded-resource

I need to display our app logo on the main page of the application but no matter what I do, nothing shows up.

```xml
<Image 
            Source="{StaticResource 'MystronicsWinder.Resources.AppIcon.appicon.svg'}"
            Margin="20"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            IsVisible="true"/>
```

[image: my static embedded image]

**UPDATE**:

```xml
<Image 
            Source="{StaticResource 'MystronicsWinder.Resources.AppIcon.appicon.png'}"
            Margin="20"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            WidthRequest="300"
            HeightRequest="300"
            IsVisible="true"/>
```

I have the same issue with my png logo!

Answer (score 0):

For displaying SVG images I use my library which you can find here: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

It uses Skia to display SVG images : https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/wiki/FreakySvgImageView

Build action of all SVG images you want to use needs to be set to EmbeddedResource.

```
   <freakyControls:FreakySvgImageView
    Command="{Binding OnTapCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding OnTapCommandParam}"
    Tapped="FreakySvgImageView_Tapped"
    SvgAssembly="{x:Static samples:Constants.SvgAssembly}"
    SvgMode="AspectFit"
    ResourceId="{x:Static samples:Constants.DotnetBot}"/>
```

Comment: It's not about the svg format I tried with png and I'm having the same issue again!

Comment: Are your Images stored with build action set to `EmbeddedResource`? if yes it won't work then change the build action to `MauiImage`

Comment: yes the build action is set to MauiImage but no image appears

Comment: If thats the case why are you giving it full path? and why are u using .png for an SVG?